# How to Add the IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point numbers from hexadecimal?

Tags: contest-math, number-systems, floating-point

Question:
Add the following IEEE 754 single-precision floating-point numbers.
(a) C0123456 + 81C564B7
(c) 5EF10324 + 5E039020

I know I first need to convert to binary, then add and later change into hexadecimal back. I tried the following approch but I get stuck in exponent thing every time.

Like, I first take binary of the given hexa decimal. Take the first bit as sign bit, the next 8 as exponent and the rest as Fraction bits.

but the part where I have to write exponent to the power of 2 in the end to add, I get confused in how to minus from 127. I tried the (a) part but the exponent I got is 3. and for the first one, I get the exponent 128. Can someone please solve atleast one of these questions so that I can get the idea?

Comment: This question about the IEEE 754 format for representing floating point numbers would rather belong to the computer science forum

Comment: Should I delete it from here?